# Displaying tomorrows day and the day after in Dutch?

Tags: javascript

I am currently using simpleWeather.js to display simple weather forecasts on my personal website. It's working great, but I am experiencing one simple issue.

Currently it outputs forecasts in English, like:

- THU: 22°C
- FRI: 26°C
- SAT: 23°C

However instead of showing "THU:" I want it to show "Donderdag:".
Obviously the same result for the remaining days of the week.

I know it's preferred to have a working code example, so I created one here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Moreab

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
  location: 'Austin, TX',
  woeid: '',
  unit: 'c',
  success: function(weather) {
 
  html = '<p>'+weather.forecast[1].day+': <i class="weerklein icon-'+weather.forecast[1].code+'"></i> min. '+weather.forecast[1].low+' max. '+weather.forecast[1].high+'</p>';
  html += '<p>'+weather.forecast[2].day+': <i class="weerklein icon-'+weather.forecast[2].code+'"></i> min. '+weather.forecast[2].low+' max. '+weather.forecast[2].high+'</p>';
  html += '<p>'+weather.forecast[3].day+': <i class="weerklein icon-'+weather.forecast[3].code+'"></i> min. '+weather.forecast[3].low+' max. '+weather.forecast[3].high+'</p>';
  html += '<p>'+weather.forecast[4].day+': <i class="weerklein icon-'+weather.forecast[4].code+'"></i> min. '+weather.forecast[4].low+' max. '+weather.forecast[4].high+'</p>';

  $("#weather").html(html);
},
error: function(error) {
  $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
}
});
});
```

It looks ugly, but it's shows exactly what I mean. As you can see it shows THU: FRI: SAT: etc...

I want those to be changed to their Dutch relatives.
Can someone tell me how to achieve this? TY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object to translate the English names to Dutch:

```
var day_to_dutch = {
    Mon: 'Maandag',
    Tue: 'Dinsdag',
    Wed: 'Woensdag',
    Thu: 'Donderdag',
    Fri: 'Vrijdag',
    Sat: 'Zaterdag',
    Sun: 'Zondag'
};
```

Translating can be done as follows:

```
day_to_dutch[weather.forecast[1].day]
```

Comment: Thank you! You are a life-saver! I spend over an hour to make this work, but I have no clue what I am doing. :P So many thanks. Will accept as best answer when time limit is over. Thank you once again.